# How to achieve KGroupTable use case in flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing some poc on flink but I am not able to find documentation around how will I achieve use case similar to KGroupTable in kafka stream as shown below

```
KTable<byte[], Long> aggregatedStream = groupedTable.aggregate(() -> 0L,
(aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + newValue.length(),
(aggKey, oldValue, aggValue) -> aggValue - oldValue.length(),  Serdes.Long(),     "aggregation-table-store");
```

Use case I want to aggregate account balance from transactions I receive. If I get an update on existing transaction Id I want to remove old value and add new value. Lets say if a transaction gets cancelled I want to remove the old value from account balance.

eg

```
TransactionId AccountId  Balance
1             account1   1000         // account1 - 1000
2             account1   2000         // account1 - 3000
3             account2   2000         // account1 - 3000, account2 - 2000
1             account1   500          // account1 - 2500, account2 - 2000
```

In above example 4th update is, i got an update on existing transaction #1 so it will remove the old balance (1000) and add new balance (500)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of how you could approach that. I used Tuples because I was lazy; it would be better to use POJOs.

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ReducingStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class TransactionsWithRetractions {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStreamSource<Tuple3<Integer, String, Float>> rawInput = env.fromElements(
                new Tuple3<>(1, "account1", 1000.0F ),
                new Tuple3<>(2, "account1", 2000.0F),
                new Tuple3<>(3, "account2", 2000.0F),
                new Tuple3<>(1, "account1", 500.0F)
        );

        rawInput
                .keyBy(t -> t.f1)
                .map(new ManageAccounts())
                .print();

        env.execute();
    }

    public static class ManageAccounts extends RichMapFunction<Tuple3<Integer, String, Float>, Tuple2<String, Float>>{
        MapStateDescriptor<Integer, Float> transactionsDesc;
        ReducingStateDescriptor<Float> balanceDesc;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            transactionsDesc = new MapStateDescriptor<Integer, Float>("transactions", Integer.class, Float.class);
            balanceDesc = new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("balance", (f, g) -> f + g, Float.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Float> map(Tuple3<Integer, String, Float> event) throws Exception {
            MapState<Integer, Float> transactions = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(transactionsDesc);
            ReducingState<Float> balance = getRuntimeContext().getReducingState(balanceDesc);

            Float currentValue = transactions.get(event.f0);
            if (currentValue == null) {
                currentValue = 0F;
            }
            transactions.put(event.f0, event.f2);
            balance.add(event.f2 - currentValue);

            return new Tuple2<>(event.f1, balance.get());
        }
    }
}
```

When run, this produces:

```
1> (account1,1000.0)
8> (account2,2000.0)
1> (account1,3000.0)
1> (account1,2500.0)
```

Note that this implementation keeps all transactions in state forever, which might become problematic in a real application, though you can scale Flink state to be very large.

Comment: i want is something different, updated an example in the question

Comment: I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: In such cases is kafka streams better as this is provided out of the box and it manages all such states in internal topics?

Comment: Support for such cases is being added to Flink's Table/SQL APIs, and I believe will be included in the upcoming Flink 1.11 release. See [FLIP-95](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=147427289) for details. This should provide the ease of use you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the update, with the code you shared, is it fault tolerant like in case cluster restarts or one node fails will getRuntimeContext will return correct MapState and ReducingState

Comment: So long as checkpointing is enabled, it will be fault tolerant.

Comment: The only disadvantage I see with this approach is we have keep such huge object of transaction and balance in our application rather than on the cluster which would make application heavy. Is there any other disadvantage of this approach

Comment: No, not that I can think of. Furthermore, keeping this state in the Flink cluster has performance advantages -- since the state is always local, this leads to high throughput and low latency. You should find this approach actually costs less to operate.

Comment: It would need to get the whole transaction object from flink cluster even if only one of the record from that transaction is required so that way its bad right even performance wise isnt it? Other thing is ofcourse the space requirement for the application also increases because the transactionstate map will be there in flink cluster as well and application as well right

Comment: Your application and the Flink cluster are the same thing. The transaction state map will be co-located with the application code -- both will be in memory, in the same JVM.